# Performance of C++ program is 2x slower with the use of TBB

Tags: c++, tbb

I'm trying to optimize the performance of a C++ program by using the TBB library.

My program only contains a couple of small for loop, so I know it can be a challenge to optimze time complexity in this case, but I have to use TBB.

As such, I tried to use a partitionner which made the program 2 time faster with TBB than without the partitionner, but it's still slower than the original program without the use of parallelism.

In my code, I print when a loop start and end with the id to see if there is parallelism. The output show that the loop is in fact execute sequentially, for example : start 1 end 1, start 2 end 2 , etc(it's a list of size 200). The output of the ids isn't random like you would expect from a parallelized program.

Here is an example of how I used the library:

```
tbb::global_control c(tbb::global_control::max_allowed_parallelism, 1000);

size_t grainsize = 1000;
    size_t changes = 0;
     tbb::parallel_for(
        tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t>(0, list.size(), grainsize), 
        [&](const tbb::blocked_range<std::size_t> r) {
          for (size_t id = r.begin(); id < r.end(); ++id) {
            std::cout << "start:" << point_id << std::endl;
            double disto = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
            size_t cluster_id = 0;
            const Point& point = points.at(id);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < short_list.size(); i++) {
              const Point& origin = originss[i];
              double disto2 = point.dist(origin);
              if (disto2 < min) {
                min = disto2;
                clus = i;
              }
            }

            if (m[id] != m_id) {
              m[id] = m_id;
              modif++;
            }
            disto_list[id] = min;
                        std::cout << "end:" << point_id << std::endl;

          }
        }
        );
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of a C++ program composed of multiple small for loops with the use of the TBB library? And why are the loop not parallized?

Comment: Do you have an outer loop around the short loops? If you do, and it's possible to do everything inside in parallel, put the `parallel_for` there.

Comment: I just tried it and while it is now 3 times faster, it is still 25% slower than the program without the implementation of TBB. There is a while true loop around the for loops, I don't know if it affect something.

Comment: You removed the `parallel_for`s for the short loops, right? It's entirely possible that you actually _can't_ speed it up using TBB too.

Comment: There is overhead for parallelism, and it seems that in your case the overhead costs are greater than the benefits you get for using it. Saying there are 5 lines of code doesn't tell us much, since those lines could be calls to expensive functions

Comment: I added the complete code of the loop, and I realized with the help of start and end printing of loop with the id of the loop, that the loops are in fact not parallized.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using task_scheduler_init in your program, then TBB uses the same thread throughout the program until task_scheduler_init objects are destroyed.

As you are passing max_allowed_parallelism as a parameter for global_control, if it is set to 1 then it will make your application run in a sequential way.
You can refer to the below link:
https://spec.oneapi.io/versions/latest/elements/oneTBB/source/task_scheduler/scheduling_controls/global_control_cls.html

It will be helpful if you provide the complete reproducer to figure out where exactly the issue took place.